# PHPUnit cannot open file

Tags: php, phpunit

I've started learning how to use PHPUnit. However, I'm facing a problem which I have no clue how to solve.

I have a folder called `lessons` and inside there is a `composer.json` which I installed PHPUnit with.
The output resulted in a folder called `vendor` and a sub-folder called `bin` which has the phpunit file in it.

In the `cmd` I typed: `cd c:/xampp/htdocs/lessons/vendor/bin`. Now the cmd folder sets to the same folder as phpunit. I've created a directory in `lessons` which I called `tests` (`lessons/tests`) which I store all of my tests in. I've created a file called `PracticeTest.php` with a very simple test script in it.

When I go back to the `cmd` and type `phpunit tests` I get `cannot open file tests.php` When I try to type `phpunit PracticeTest` I get `cannot open file PracticeTest.php`. When I try `phpunit tests/PracticeTest` (with `.php` or without) I get the same error that the file could not be opened.

My suspicious that it has something to do with that face that the `cmd` is pointing at the `lessons/vendor/bin` directory, but I'm not sure if it is really the problem or how to fix it.

just to arrange the paths:

- `lessons\vendor\bin\`
- `lessons\tests\`
- `lessons\tests\PracticeTest.php`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PHP usually shows you the complete path it was trying to access. Check this and compare it to the actual path's. This should show you what went wrong.

Comment: I had just had the same problem. I executed `phpunit --bootstrap bootstrap.php PracticeTest` while being in the came directory as the PracticeTest.php but I was using `chdir()` in my bootstrap file

Answer (score 8):

Go to path project:

```
D:\>cd www
D:\wwww>cd lessons
```

And execute:

```
D:\www\lessons>vendor\bin\phpunit tests

PHPUnit 4.8.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
.....E.
Time: 1.34 seconds, Memory: 5.50MB
There was 1 error:
1) UserTest::it_should_be_able_to_construct
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #1 (No Value) of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert
:assertInstanceOf() must be a class or interface name
D:\www\lessons\tests\UserTest.php:10
FAILURES!
Tests: 7, Assertions: 4, Errors: 1.
```

> It Works!!!!

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit ./tests/PracticeTest
```

Comment: vendor/bin/phpunit  C:\xampp\htdocs\unit_test_2\tests\CalculatorTest.php  work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same, but if you type `phpunit` then tab you will see what directory you are in and it should autosuggest. Then navigate to your test file.

Answer (score 0):

I had `include_path` sections separated by comma. It has to be semicolon on Windows.

Comment: use PATH_SEPARATOR constant like 
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').PATH_SEPARATOR.'C:/PHP/PEAR/PHPUnit');

Answer (score 0):

I have created a phpunit.bat in the root folder of my project containing

```
@ECHO OFF SET BIN_TARGET=%~dp0/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit php "%BIN_TARGET%" %*
```

Now it works.